# Blurry AI or EPS previews in the links panel in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, images

I am using ID CC 2017.1 and have noticed this strange issue when using Illustrator or EPS files. They display fine in the actual document, but in the links panel, the image shows as blurry. My view setting is set to High Quality. So, what would be causing the links panel to show the link image in this way?

[image: screenshot from InDesign to show problem]

Comment: Your view settings only affect the artwork on the page. The links panel just shows a thumbnail, which I guess is quite low quality. On a side note, _pink grapefruit balsam cream vinegar_?!?

Answer (score 2):

The Links panel preview is only there for visual reference. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense for InDesign to waste system resources to provide high quality previews in the Links Panel.

This behavior is 100% normal. The links panel thumbnails are for *reference*. The Links panel is not an "image browser".